# How to run javascript in background?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have created plugin for background service (to run the application in background) in phonegap .I have created service for run the application in background using android.Then start the service from plugin.In index.html I call that plugin in button click event.When I click the button the service is started.
    Is it possible using android service run the javascript in background and get alert from background?how to do that?
    Now I want to run the javascript in background.Is it possible how to get alert  in background.also need to call the wcf rest service.

please guide me.thanks in advance.

My code in Index.html

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady()
{
alert("hello");
navigator.notification.alert("hai");
}
```

after starting service My application is run in background.I want this "alert("hello");""navigator.notification.alert("hai");" in background.(ie) alert found in my .html file.But you give code for activity in android.It should run the javascript in background and display alert from that.please guide me.thanks in advance.I have one more doubt this service also run my wcf rest service in background and diaplay alert from that service. please tell me the solution
My code for service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();


        Toast.makeText(this, "alert Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In this code I have add one player.so after starting service .song is played in foreground,song is played, after pressing home button in emulator(background).I want to show alert like this.how to do that?

In my plugin

```
if (CALL_SERVICE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CALL_SERVICE_ACTION");

    ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, MyService.class));
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, AppNotification.class);
    ctx.startActivity(i);

}
```

I have call your activity after starting service It show alert only in fore ground after pressing home button in emulator.the alert not come( from background)please tell me solution

In index.html

```
function callServiceFunction() {
window.plugins.BackgroundService.callService('callService',
        callServiceSuccessCallBack, callServiceFailCallBack);
     }
function callServiceSuccessCallBack(e) {
alert("Success");
callNotificationsFunction();
}

function callServiceFailCallBack(f) {
alert("Failure");
}
function callNotificationsFunction() {

       window.plugins.BackgroundService.callNotifications('callNotifications',
callNotificationsSuccessCallBack, callNotificationsFailCallBack); 

}
function callNotificationsSuccessCallBack(e) {
alert("Success");
}

function callNotificationsFailCallBack(f) {
alert("Failure");
}
```

while I am clicking background button service created.and It call callNotificationFunction from callservicesuccesscallback.it display alert in foreground.after I am clicking home button in emulator nothing happend, alert not dispalyed from background, please guide me thanks in advance.If I call callNotificationFunction in separate button click nothing happend(alert is not displayed in foreground) and no error in logcat

Comment: When do you want to give the notifications?When the Service starts or  the notifications are dynamic ?

Comment: When i click the button my service started.Then i should get the alert both in foreground and background.(alert in my index.html)eg:alert("hello") and my wcf rest service also run in background.please guide me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show alert in your background. Create an Activity which runs as a dialog.
For example create an activity like this

```
public class AppNotification extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppNotification.this)
            .create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Something");

    alertDialog.setButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();                       
                }
            }); 
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Also In manifest file use this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".AppNotification"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
 </activity>
```

And Call this activity when ever you want to show some notifications like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, AppNotification.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

In Order to Give Notifications use

```
navigator.notification.alert("hai"); // For foreground
window.plugins.BackgroundService.callNotifications('callNotifications',
callNotificationsSuccessCallBack, callNotificationsFailCallBack); // For Background
```

Just as you used service plugin to call the service you use the call notifications.And then perform the actions like this

```
else if (CALL_NOTIFICATION_ACTION.equals(action)) {
Log.d(TAG, "CALL_NOTIFICATION_ACTION");

Intent i = new Intent(ctx, AppNotification.class);
context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have edited my post .please see that .and  please guide me.thanks in advance

Comment: Hey listen,Again create a plugin and call the activity which i shared to show notification.Its simple....

Comment: I have doubt in your reply. By using service in android already created aplugin for run application in background.so how to call this (AppNotification)activity in that plugin I have edited my post please see that .guide me,thanks in advance

Comment: hai,I have edited my post please see that and guide me, thanks in advance

Comment: Where are the logs? And have you invoked this plugin at all to get the output?

Comment: I have called this function "callnotificationServiceFunction()"  in callServiceSuccessCallBack(e) of callserviceFunction() .I didnot get error in logcat.alert come only in foreground.alert not come in background (while clicking home button).please see Myservice.java In that java file I added a player that played (after starting service) continuously(both foreground and also after clicking home button-background).how to display alert like that.please guide me.thanks in advance

Comment: I Cant tell what is the problem without any error.In your plugin see whether Log.d(TAG, "CALL_NOTIFICATION_ACTION"); is giving value... Try to debug and check where the connection is breaking...Is it going in the AppNotification Activity or not?

Comment: please see my edited post,and tell me the solution.thanks in advance

Comment: I get alert in foreground while clicking button.My only problem is after clicking home button alert not displayed(from background).while I am clicking home button ,service run in background but alert not come.please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I still cant say.. Try running that APPNotification activity as a seperate android project.See wheter you are able to call that or not...

Comment: activity is only started in foreground.so alert only displayed in foreground, how to start the activity in background and displayed alert from background?( I think start activity from MyService.java  Is it correct or not,Is it possible how to do that?)please guide me.thanks in advance.

Comment: No You wont be able to connect to javascript from MyService.java

Comment: I have one doubt: wcf rest service(get data from server and post data to server-using ajax and jquery) in phonegap run in background or not after starting android service.If it is possible,how to display alert each time the wcf rest service call from background.please tell me using android service run the wcf rest service of phonegap in background or not.If it is possible tell me the solution.otherwise in which way run phonegap wcf restservice from background .guide me.tell me the solution.

Comment: Just as i told you to display the notification the best way is to open a activity in Dialog mode... Thats all...

Comment: Ok, how to display notification for each time phonegap wcfservice call from background .please tell me.thanks in advance

Comment: how to findout  phonegap wcfservice  is called while application running in background.lease tell me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can run Javascript in the background on Android using a Service, a WebView and WindowManager. Check out this post [here](https://medium.com/@oriharel/how-to-run-javascript-code-in-a-background-service-on-android-8ec1a12ebe92).